# ADC with better performance

Tags: arduino-mega, voltage-level, adc, raspberrypi, analog-sampling

I need to sample voltage at a very high rate (say for like 10000 Hz) and with a very good precision(at least 10-12 bit ADC will do). So I am in need of an Analog-to-Digital Converter(ADC) which has a very high sampling rate (sampling rate has to be constant and known), can be interfaced with Arduino Mega or Raspberry Pi and noise should be neligible to minimum level of voltage magnitude that it can count. Can anyone suggests me with any ADC that follows these characteristics?

Comment: You mean like an external ADC chip?  What about a [TeensyLC](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensylc.html) or [Teensy3.6](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy36.html) instead?  About 100KHz 12-bit ADC, if that's accurate enough.  You could edit your question and say what "very good precision" actually means.

Comment: Define "very good precision". Define "high sampling rate". Define "negligible noise". What is the maximum voltage you need to measure? Your idea of "very good precision" and mine might vary by a considerable amount. You know that the chip vendors (like DigiKey) have search parameters that let you type in the things you want and it returns the chips that meet those requirements?

Comment: What are you planning to do with these figures? At 10000 samples per second, where are you going to store them? RAM? Disk? If in RAM you will soon run out of RAM on most microcontrollers after a second or so. If on disk, the speed of writing to disk will slow you down. So another question is: How many samples are you planning to capture?

Comment: I am trying to calculate total harmonic distortion of line voltage. I've already tried with Arduino Mega. I can store 3200 number of sample data into it's storage. The ADC captures data for like only 0.4 second but that's sufficient for me. The problem is, Arduinos ADC sampling rate can't be easlity determined and it adds some noise to obtained data I guess.Besides Arduino can't transmit data over serial port at a fast rate.

Comment: So now I'm thingking of using another ADC and interfacing it directly with Raspberry Pi and transmit sampled data directly to the Pi(if possible). Maximum volatge doesn't matter beacuse I'll have it stepped down and shifted within ADC voltage range.@NickGammon

Comment: If you change the prescaler you can get something like 76000 conversions per second on the AVR chip at (slightly less than) 10 bit resolution. See http://www.gammon.com.au/adc

Comment: > The problem is,  using Ann external ADC solves none of those problems for you.

Answer (score 3):

[ADS7835](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads7835.pdf) from Texas Instrument.

> can be interfaced with Arduino Mega or Raspberry Pi

It is interfaced through SPI, 12 bit data, and up to 500kHz throughput rate.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to sample voltage at a very high rate (say for like 10000 Hz) and with a very good precision(at least 10-12 bit ADC will do).

10Ksps and 12bit-resolution adcs are fairly common for onboard ADC. you should be able to find lots of mcus that have adc modules that can do that.

even for an external adc, that's not difficult at all. because of the speed, you are likely looking at a spi adc module.

precision is another matter.